# Steam not responsive in browser (Wine)

Tags: wine, steam

When I open up Steam through Wine, it becomes unresponsive and only partially loads the page in Store, Community and "User". But, I can access Library and click on things in it.

[Screenshot of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lComx.png)

Comment: This appears to be a cross platform issue as well with wine. This is happening on Mac OSX as well. :(